# Scene is unreachable (XCODE 5 iOS developer)

Tags: ios, xcode, scene

I am new to iOS developing and I hit an error saying "Scene is untraceable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime" I was wondering how to fix this problem? As I have no idea how too haha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix this by giving your viewController a storyboard Id

Or you need to make sure it has a segue to another controller, in short a view controller must be reachable.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct solution, it's worked for me before, but now I am getting the warning for a UIViewController in my storyboard that is linked via a seque to main view controller. I've also given it a storyboardID, but still get the warning. I've cleaned the project, deleted derived data, and restarted Xcode, but still there in Xcode 5.1.1?

Comment: Very strange, I suggest you to go through your storyboard and click on each ViewController and assign the id. use the left pane to select each, see this pic http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cq9X.png

Comment: I owe meda a coke. I stared just by zooming out of storyboard to see all view controllers, then clicked on the warning again, and this time it selected a different view in the Document Outline (the left pop out that lists storyboard objects), which was (as usual) a navigation view controller, and adding the storyboard fixed it of course. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As meda answered, view controller must be reachable with a storyboard id either with a segue.

Before you give storyboard IDs to all of your views or make segue links to them, make sure you don't have any "duplicated" view stacking on the original view. pressing 'Cmd C and Cmd V' makes that happen.
so, drag around your views one by one to reveal duplicated views.

Double clicking that warning message helps you focus on the view causing the problem as well.

Comment: Perfect, a rogue cmd-c cmd-v had given me a stealthy duplicate and I didn't think to check.